# How to get active tab in a Safari App Extension?

Tags: swift, macos, safari, safari-app-extension

When I follow the Apple example I always get a `nil` `activeTab`:

```
override func toolbarItemClicked(in window: SFSafariWindow) {
    // This method will be called when your toolbar item is clicked.

    window.getActiveTab(completionHandler: { (activeTab) in
        print(activeTab)
        activeTab?.getActivePage(completionHandler:  { (activePage) in
            print(activePage)
            activePage?.getPropertiesWithCompletionHandler( { (properties) in
                print(properties)
                if properties?.url != nil {
                    let urlString = properties!.url.absoluteString
                    print("URL!", urlString)
                    let videoURL = self.youtubeDl(urlString: urlString)
                    if videoURL != nil {
                        window.openTab(with: videoURL!, makeActiveIfPossible: true, completionHandler: nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is a getActiveTab:

```
SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow { (window) in
    window?.getActiveTab { (tab) in 
        tab?.getActivePage(completionHandler: { (page) in
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, is this getActiveTab an async method?

Answer (score 6):

Your Safari App Extension can only access the tabs of sites your extension is configured to access.

In your Info.plist, verify that the [**SFSafariWebsiteAccess** dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariAppExtension_PG/infoplist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017319-CH5-SW43):

- Has a **Level** equal to "**Some**" or "**All**".
- Has all required domains listed in the **Allowed Domains** array (if Level="**Some**").

Be aware that your extension's website access permissions are displayed in **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Extensions**. You are encouraged to limit your website access to "Some" (and explicit domains) unless you really do require access to every website.

Comment: So there is nothing like [`activeTab` in WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#activeTab_permission)?

Answer (score 1):

You should go to info.plist, `NSExtension->SFSafariWebsiteAccess` and set something ( for example * - for all sites) to Allowed domains. Without this option, I always got nil from the window. I think your extension doesn't work if the site is not allowed.